# what is exactly Publisher confirms in Rabbitmq?

Tags: rabbitmq

I read the [official document](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#publisher-confirms) of Rabbitmq, it is not really clear for me what was that?
its something like `Consumer Ack` but with a difference that the `Publisher Confirm` is send by rabbitmq server to Publisher client when the server get the message from publisher client?

Can someone explain more about it?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> its something like Consumer Ack but with a difference that the
> Publisher Confirm is send by rabbitmq server to Publisher client when
> the server get the message from publisher client?

Yes. When you enable publisher confirms, and your publisher receives acknowledgement that the message is published, you can be **certain** of it.

Without publisher confirms, you can lose messages in several cases. One example: your application could publish the data to the TCP buffer, but then crash, or the server itself could crash. Another example: a network device could fail mid-delivery. Another example: RabbitMQ itself could crash after receiving the TCP data containing your message.